# WhatsApp can't be reinstalled on iPhone 5s

Tags: iphone, whatsapp.app

I accidentally deleted my WhatsApp just now. When I try to reinstall it, it has an iCloud icon on it. Clicking it, it just say "You already purchased this, so it will be downloaded now at no additional charge". But then when I clicked "ok" it doesn't even start downloading. I've waited for 30 minutes but it didn't start to download.

What should I do now?

Comment: Are you able to download other apps?  I want to make sure it's not something in your network connection, iPhone,  etc.

Comment: Try to restart your phone, that usually does the trick